# Creating an asio wrapper around legacy API with a virtual callback

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a legacy library interfacing with hardware, which is already asynchronous (via interrupts), but would like to create an asio based interface over it. The problem is, that the asio examples of binding callback based APIs all have possibilities to pass handlers directly via function parameters. But this API works like this:

```
class WriterBase 
{
public:
    ...

    bool writeMessage(Packet* pkt)
    {
        ...
    }

    virtual wroteMessage(Packet* pkt) = 0;
};
```

So, one is expected to derive from this class, call `writeMessage()` and get the callback in the overridden `wroteMessage()` function, passing of some handler can practically only be done via the class instance itself.

The application using this API uses asio with C++20 coroutines and this function will be co_await'ed using `use_awaitable`.

I am a bit lost now at how to create a send_async function with correct asio handling. The simplest solution (suggested from ChatGPT) is to create a `std::promise`, get it's future and set the value of the promise in the `wroteMessage()` function. But this makes it effectively blocking the thread.

Trying around with the example [asio callback example](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.28.0/src/examples/cpp20/operations/callback_wrapper.cpp), but I couldn't come up with a solution that can pass the handler correctly to the `wroteMessage()` function. I get into a lot of template mess, where it is not entirely clear to me, how to do this correctly.

How to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a bit more elaborate example (with a lot more comments):

```
// This class is from a legacy library and cannot be changed
#include <array>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

// Normally, this is a class
using Packet = std::array<uint8_t, 1024>;

class WriterBase
{
public:
    virtual ~WriterBase() {}

    void writeMessage(Packet *pkt)
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;

        // Simulation. In reality, the data of the packet
        // is passed down to a driver which uses DMA to
        // transfer the data. When finished, the device
        // notifies via interrupt that the message has been
        // written and calls wroteMessage.
        std::thread(
            [this, pkt]
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
                bool ret = wroteMessage(pkt);
                if (ret)
                {
                    delete pkt;
                }
            })
            .detach();
    }

protected:
    virtual bool wroteMessage(Packet *pkt) = 0;
};

// Derived class, under my control
class Writer : public WriterBase
{
protected:
    virtual bool wroteMessage(Packet *pkt) override
    {
        // Called by interrupt service routine in its own
        // thread

        // Here we should notify asio, that he operation is
        // finished, aka the completion handler should be
        // invoked

        // if we return true, the packet will be
        // deleted by the legacy library.
        // If we return false, we need to take care of this
        return true;
    }
};

int main_without_asio()
{
    auto writer = std::make_unique<Writer>();
    std::atomic<bool> terminate{false};

    while (!terminate.load())
    {
        // Some example. In reality, gets data from a network, converts
        // it into the packet and sends it to the device
        Packet *pkt = new Packet();
        writer->writeMessage(pkt);

        // other code continues here, wroteMessage will be called
        // and a synchronized action is done, either via atomics
        // or via a promise/future pair, where wroteMessage sets
        // the result of the promise.
    }
    return 0;
}

// This is what I am aiming for
int main_with_asio()
{
    asio::io_context context;
    std::atomic<bool> terminate{false};

    asio::co_spawn(
        context,
        [&terminate]
        {
            auto writer = std::make_unique<Writer>();

            while (!terminate.load())
            {
                // Some example. In reality, gets data from a network, converts
                // it into the packet and sends it to the device
                Packet *pkt = new Packet();
                co_await writer->write_async(pkt, asio::use_awaitable);
            }
        },
        asio::detached);

    context.run();
    return 0;

}
```

So, basically the API is already async, and `wroteMessage()` is the "completion handler" of the `writeMessage` call. I have not callback parameters like a function pointer with user data or `std::function`. To pass data between `writeMessage` and `wroteMessage` (which as I understand would be necessary for a CompletionToken handler) is basically only possible via a member variable of the Writer class. Or are there other possibilities, which I am just not seeing?

I hope, this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Have you looked into `async_compose`? The example/explanation isn't particularly good, but it basically gives you a facility to do "something" as an asynchronous operation, and your something can then invoke the completion handler when it's done.
They focus on composing asio-async operations, but it would still be my first idea when trying to interface with something else. After all, you calling "complete" shouldn't depend too much on what happens before that...

Comment: I had a more detailed look at it now. All these solutions rely on passing in a continuation or completion handler as a parameter (e.g. the std::move(self) in the compose example. The API I have to use does not allow this as the callback (wroteMessage) is called from the hardware interrupt and I have no parameters to pass through. So I cannot pass a completion handler directly to the callback and would have to temporarily store it in a member variable of the derived class. Which is kind of tricky to get the type right.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine a simple emulation of your API:

```
using Packet = std::string;
void writeMessage(Packet msg, std::function<void(Packet)> wroteMessage) {
    std::thread([=] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        wroteMessage(msg);
    }).detach();
}
```

A simple demo as-is (**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a898df2451d0a9b5)**):

```
auto trace() { return std::osyncstream(std::cout); }

void demoClassic() {
    writeMessage("oldfashioned",
                 [](Packet const& msg) { trace() << "completed " << quoted(msg) << std::endl; });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1500ms);
}
```

Prints the expected:

```
completed "oldfashioned"
```

### Async Initiation

To work seemlessly with Asio the 'golden path' is to [write an initiation function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html#:%7E:text=In%20practice%20we%20should%20call%20the%20async_initiate%20helper%20function), where the completion semantics are chosen by the completion token:

```
template <typename Token> auto asyncWrite(Packet msg, Token&& token) {
    auto init = [](auto completion_handler, Packet msg) {
        writeMessage(std::move(msg), std::move(completion_handler));
    };

    return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(Packet)>(init, token, std::move(msg));
}
```

Which can be used in various ways: [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7a023f02a8d59e9)

```
void demoAsio() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    auto work = make_work_guard(ioc);

    asyncWrite("asio style", [](Packet const& msg) { trace() << "callback " << quoted(msg) << std::endl; });

    std::future<Packet> fut = asyncWrite("asio style", asio::use_future);

    ioc.run_for(1500ms);

    trace() << "future " << quoted(fut.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
completed "oldfashioned"
callback "asio style"
future "asio style"
```

Adding c++23 coros: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/W77bhMcjb)**

```
asio::awaitable<void> cpp20_coro() {
    Packet msg = co_await asyncWrite("cpp20 rocks", asio::deferred);
    trace() << "cpp20 style " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}
```

Or instead using Boost Context for coroutines: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/W77bhMcjb)**

```
void stackful_coro(asio::yield_context yield) {
    Packet msg = asyncWrite("cpp11 rocks too", yield);
    trace() << "stackful_coro " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}
```

### Notes

In practice you will want to make a work-guard part of the operation so the user doesn't have to worry about it.

### Listing For Reference

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::literals;

using Packet = std::string;
void writeMessage(Packet msg, std::move_only_function<void(Packet)> wroteMessage) {
    std::thread([=, f = std::move(wroteMessage)]() mutable {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::move(f)(msg);
    }).detach();
}

void demoClassic();
void demoAsio();

int main() {
    demoClassic();
    demoAsio();
}

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>

auto trace() { return std::osyncstream(std::cout); }

void demoClassic() {
    writeMessage("oldfashioned",
                 [](Packet const& msg) { trace() << "completed " << quoted(msg) << std::endl; });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1500ms);
}

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

template <typename Token> auto asyncWrite(Packet msg, Token&& token) {
    auto init = [](auto completion_handler, Packet msg) {
        writeMessage(std::move(msg), std::move(completion_handler));
    };

    return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(Packet)>(init, token, std::move(msg));
}

asio::awaitable<void> cpp20_coro() {
    Packet msg = co_await asyncWrite("cpp20 rocks", asio::deferred);
    trace() << "cpp20 style " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}

void stackful_coro(asio::yield_context yield) {
    Packet msg = asyncWrite("cpp11 rocks too", yield);
    trace() << "stackful_coro " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
}

void demoAsio() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    auto work = make_work_guard(ioc);

    asyncWrite("asio style", [](Packet const& msg) { trace() << "callback " << quoted(msg) << std::endl; });

    std::future<Packet> fut = asyncWrite("asio style", asio::use_future);

    co_spawn(ioc, cpp20_coro, asio::detached);
    spawn(ioc, stackful_coro);

    ioc.run_for(1500ms);

    trace() << "future " << quoted(fut.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

Local output:

```
 $ time ./build/sotest
completed "oldfashioned"
callback "asio style"
cpp20 style "cpp20 rocks"
stackful_coro "cpp11 rocks too"
future "asio style"

real    0m3,006s
user    0m0,006s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I really appreciate that! My problem though is, that this solution relies on the second (std::function) parameter in writeMessage. I don't have this parameter and cannot change this library. So I cannot pass the completion handler to the callback wroteMessage. This callback is called from the hardware from an interrupt routine deep in the legacy library. As far as I understand, I would need a member in the derived class to temporarily hold the completion handler until the wroteMessage function is called, use it there to notify asio, and then remove it.

Comment: @MichaelO Can you make a self-contained example? I cannot really think of a useful example that combines `writeMessage` **AND** `wroteMessage` in the same type, and neither am I sure about the lifetime and ownership of `Packet*`. Once I see what it actually looks like, I can see help. This is always the guideline by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did some updates to the question, I hope this clears it up a bit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MichaelO can you please review the syntax errors in there? I - once again - cannot think of useful ways to fix it without substantially altering semantics (e.g. the very first `std::thread` constructor can be fixed syntactically but will by definition throw immediately from the destructor) (did you OCR this from an image?)

Comment: There's a lot weird about that interface. Besides the missing virtual destructor (that really is a footgun) is there a situation where `wroteMessage` is called with a different `Packet*` than `wirteMessage`? If not, that would hugely simplify things.

Comment: Here's my simplest suggestion - still like to get your thoughts, at least before I make a more advanced version: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a64dd10e8017cb5

Comment: oh, I see, yes ,the destructor is virtual, sorry, did some updates to the code. And yes, the `Packet*` in wroteMessage is always the same. As for the API: welcome to my world! It's written in C++03 style with a very strong C-flavour (embedded dev wrote it).

Yes, I think your current solution is what I am looking for. So if I understand correctly, you use asios type erasure and store the handler in a member, and additionally use a strand to ensure the handler is on the same thread, correct?

Comment: Since the entire thing is still singlethreaded, the strand is actually not required. (Also, coroutines are implicit strands - so unless you're sharing resources outside the coro frame there is still no need for strand). The reason I added the strand was as check for the callback invocation, e.g. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a9d6c60e3409437

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears things up. Would you add your example to the answer, so that I can mark it as a solution?